# How to synchronize multiple animated PNG images on HTML webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, optimization, background-image

Two animated PNG images are loaded as `background-images` in CSS on a HTML webpage, see code below. Each image animates one frame per second, and loops.

The trouble is, both animated PNG images load at slightly different times, therefore the animations begin at different times, and appear unsynchronized.

**Question: How do I get both animated PNG images to start animating at the same time, after the page has loaded, so that both images appear in sync as frames of each image change?**

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="car"> ... </div>
<div class="bus"> ... </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.car {
  background-image: url('car.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top left;
  background-size: 400px 200px;
}

.bus {
  background-image: url('bus.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom right;
  background-size: 600px 300px;
}
```

Comment: Combine the images to a [sprite sheet](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any control over the timing of animations loaded in an image.  If your animations cannot be combined into a single image, you must do the animation client-side.